# Extending a distribution continuously to $C_c^N (\Omega)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a domain and let $u\in D'(\Omega)$ be a distribution of order $\leq N$.

> How can we show that $u$ can be continuously extended to $C_c^N(\Omega)$?

By "continuously extended" I mean: extending $u$ to a linear functional on $C_c^N(\Omega)$ such that if $f_n, f$ have the same compact support and $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $C^N$, then $u(f_n)\rightarrow u(f)$

Answer (score 1):

First prove

for any $\phi\in C^{N}_c(\Omega)$, we can find a sequence $\phi_v\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ supported in fixed compact neighborhood $K$ of support of $\phi$ such that

$$\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup|\partial^{\alpha}\phi - \partial^{\alpha}\phi_v|\to 0,\quad v\to \infty$$

And define $u(\phi) = \lim u(\phi_v)$. The limit exists since

$|u(\phi_v) - u(\phi_w)| = |u(\phi_v-\phi_w)|\le C\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup|\partial^{\alpha}(\phi_v-\phi_w)|\to 0$.

Comment: I've actually done that, the only problem that remained is to prove the continuity requirement in the question (i.e. if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $C^N$ and all functions have the same compat support, then $u(f_n) \rightarrow u(f)$). Why is it true?

Comment: I recommend you to read the first book of Lars Hormander's series on differential operators.@ext, that is just a theorem in that book.

Comment: @ext This is a general fact for uniformly continuous functions, so in particular for linear maps: Let $X$ be a topological vector space, $Y$ a dense subspace, $v\colon Y \to C$ a continuous linear functional, then there is a unique continuous extension $w\colon X \to C$ of $v$. And $w$ is constructed as above, i.e. $w(\phi) = \lim v(\phi_\nu)$ for a sequence $(\phi_\nu)$ in $Y$ converging to $\phi\in X$ and does not depend on the chosen sequence.